# How to add a custom build script to IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a simple way to configure a totally custom build process for a *non-Java project* in IntelliJ IDEA? Basically, I just need to run a custom shell command instead of any smarter build processes.

Comment: what kind of project is it?

Comment: It's a D project, but this is definitely irrelevant to the question because I am looking a way to run my own build commands on this project. At the same time I like IDEA for its integration with VCS, that's why I'm looking for a way to use it in any possible project.

Answer (score 7):

Try configuring these shell commands as custom tools (File > Settings > Tools > External Tools).

You can then assign keys for invoking them (e.g Ctrl + F9) in  File > Settings > Keymap > Main menu > External Tools > [Your tool name]