# Using IntelliJ IDEA for project using Makefiles

Tags: intellij-idea, makefile, ant

An existing Java project uses makefiles (which in turn uses ANT).

I want to work on this project using IntelliJ IDEA. However, no IntelliJ specific files, e.g. project files, should be checked in to version control.

How can I configure the project so that:

1. Makefiles can be run from inside IntelliJ IDEA.
2. Change `Build > Make Project` so that it either does nothing or runs some make target (in a makefile). I do not want to the standard behavior of compiling into `./bin` since this potentially can conflict with the makefiles.

Comment: You might have a partial answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100649/how-to-add-a-custom-build-script-to-idea

Although it seems there is no way to integrate it with `Build > Make Project`

Answer (score 1):

## For Windows users

So far, the guidance provided by Dannil Maslov ( [see intelliJ IDEA thread here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000029230/comments/360001910439) )  worked for me.

1. Install [GnuWin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/getgnuwin32/) (Make for Windows).
2. Install the [IDEA  Makefile plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9333-makefile-language).
3. Go to settings and specify the path to make executable under: File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Make | Path to Make executable (by default: C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe). Check "Use Cygwin" if necessary.

If you have used chocolatey ( `choco install make` ) , change the path in step 3 accordingly.

You should be up and running.

Comment: I installed GnuWin32 as mentioned in step 1. I did not come across any errors during the installation. I do not see "make" in the folder GnuWin32\bin\. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

A [compilation database feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/compilation-database.html) became available in 2018.

The help page says:

> **Make-based projects**:
> The [compiledb-generator tool](https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb) creates compilation databases for make-based build systems.
>
> **Bear and intercept-build tools**:
> [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) and [intercept-build](https://github.com/rizsotto/scan-build) from scan-build are the tools to help you get a compilation database by intercepting compiler calls during the build.

(Bear and intercept-build work on Linux, by injecting themselves into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`)

Comment: I guess this is for Linux. If so, mention it in the first line so that people can quickly get to know the platform for which the solution applicable